# Proving that the matrix representation of a nilpotent linear operator is upper-triangular with diagonal entries $ = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence

Let T be a nilpotent operator on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, and suppose that $p$ is the smallest positive integer for which $T^P=T_0$ (zero-transformation).

I have so far proved the following subquestions:

- $N(T^i) \subseteq N(T^{i+1})$ for every positive integer $i$
- There is a sequence of ordered bases $\beta_1, \beta_2, ..., \beta_p$ such that $\beta_i$ is a basis for $N(T^i)$ and $\beta_{i+1}$ contains $\beta_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq p-1$

Now, I must show that if $\beta = \beta_p$ is the ordered basis for $N(T^p) = V$ constructed so that it contains all the previous $\beta_i$, then $[T]_\beta$ is upper-triagular with diagonal entries being zero

I'm having a hard time showing this, and even seeing why this is true.

The two statements I was asked to prove above implies that I can have a scenario where $T^1$ has an empty nullspace. This doesn't violate $N(T) \subseteq N(T^2)$ nor $\{\emptyset\} = \beta_1 \subseteq \beta_2$.

But in that case, the first element of $\beta$ (denoted $v_1$) is not in the kernel of $T$. So $T(v_1) \neq 0$, and this contradicts what I am supposed to prove.

Could someone help me understand where my logic is breaking down, and how one could show the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is breaks down when you try to show $T$ is nilpotent. If $T$ has *trivial* nullspace (we can never have an empty nullspace), then $T$ has full rank and is invertible. Invertible matrices can never be nilpotent; we can just multiply $T^n = 0$ both sides by $T^{-1}$ $n$ times to get $I = 0$, a contradiction.

To prove this result, note that $T$ maps $N(T^{i+1})$ into $N(T^i)$. So, if $v \in \beta_{i+1}$, then $Tv \in \operatorname{span}(\beta_i)$. So, when you form your basis $\beta$, the image of each basis vector lies in the span of the basis vectors before it in the basis (**not** including itself). That is, if $\beta = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, then
$$T(v_i) = a_{1i} v_1 + a_{2i} v_2 + \ldots + a_{(i-1)i}v_{i-1} + \color{red}0v_i + 0v_{i+1} + \ldots + 0v_n.$$
When forming the matrix for $T$ with respect to basis $\beta$, this turns into a column vector, placed in the matrix so that the red $0$ lies on the diagonal. This makes the matrix upper triangular, with a $0$ diagonal.

Comment: I see. Is the inclusion of the basis $\beta_i$ and $\beta_{i+1}$ supposed to be a strict inclusion? Because otherwise, is it not possible that $\beta_i = \beta_{i+1}$, and so in your example $Tv \in \text{span}(\beta_i) = \text{span}(\beta_{i+1})$, and the diagonal entry is not necessarily $0$?

Comment: And furthermore, I cannot see why there would be a strict inclusion. I understand your argument for $T^1$ not having a trivial nullspace, but I can't see a reason why $\beta_i \neq \beta_{i+1}$

Comment: @mynamejeff Inclusion from $N(T^i)$ to $N(T^{i+1})$ is strict, until it isn't, in which case the nullspace of $N(T^i)$ fails to ever grow again. If $N(T^i) = N(T^{i+1})$, you can prove that $N(T^{i+2}) = N(T^{i+1})$, and so on. When $T$ is nilpotent, $N(T^i)$ grows until $N(T^i)$ eventually encompasses the entire domain of $T$ (in particular at $i = p$). The nullspace of $N(T^i)$ cannot stop growing until then, so strict inclusion does indeed occur.

Comment: @mynamejeff To prove the claim in my previous comment, suppose $v \in N(T^{i+2})$. Then $T^{i+1}(Tv) = 0$, so $Tv \in N(T^{i+1}) = N(T^i)$. Thus $T^{i+1}v = T^i(Tv) = 0$, hence $v \in N(T^{i+1})$.